# Digital Sound Processing in C# (and possibly SilverLight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, audio, signal-processing

I need to do some basic and non basic DSP programming in C#. At its core, it includes the generation of a sin wave deciding its frequency in Hertz. Then I'd like to Frequency Modulate it and maybe filter it.

Can you suggest any library to help me? Ideally this should also work in a SilverLight environment, as my aim is to showcase a ultra-basic SilverLight synthesizer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out a couple of articles by Charles Petzold:

[A Simple Silverlight Synthesizer](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/07/A-Simple-Silverlight-3-Synthesizer-with-Keyboard-of-Sorts.html)

and

[A simple electronice Sequencer in Silverlight](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/07/Simple-Electronic-Music-Sequencer-for-Silverlight.html)

The Oscillator class in the SimpleSequencer project might be what you're looking for.